# How to dispatch an event to other object

Tags: java, dispatcher

I just want to call my button to do what i've set up using ".**setOnMouseClicked**(event -> {});", but by clicking an **enter button**. So i think i have to dispatch an event but i don't know how.
Summarizing the problem - button has to do thing - which it does when i click the mouse - but after pressing the enter button.

I'm dispatching an event using '.getEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent([here i don't know what to type][same there])

```
// i tried that
if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
  EventDispatcher dispatcher = new EventDispatcher() {
    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
      return null; 
    }
  };
  someButton.getEventDispatcher().dispatchEvent([Event], [EventDispatcher]));
}
// it does nothing btw
```

Comment: cant you directly reference the method you are passing to the setOnMouseCliked ?

Comment: It is ugly way and i have like ~ 15 buttons. it'll be huge mess

Comment: What kind of buttons do you use ? Most implement a .click() function

Comment: These buttons are handmade by me using StackPane

Comment: then why not just add a public click function that indirectly calls the function you set it to do ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html says you can just call onMouseClicked() on your button